# How do I create a template object based off of user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, queue

I have made an array based queue with a template so that the user can decide what kind of data is held inside the queue but I cannot figure out how gather input and then from that create a queue of that data type.

Here is my Queue

```
    #include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<class itemType>

class Queue
{
private:
   unique_ptr<itemType []> queueArray;
   int queueSize;
   int front;
   int rear;
   int numItems;
public:
   Queue(int);
   itemType peekFront();
   void enqueue(itemType item);
   void dequeue();
   bool isEmpty() const;
   bool isFull() const;
   void clear();
};
```

And I have tried this and many other ways but cant figure out how to tell what type of data the user inputs and then create a Queue with that type of data.

```
    int main()
{
    const int MAXSIZE = 5;
    int choice;

    cout << "1. integer queue\n" << "2. string queue\n" << "3. float queue\n";
    choice = menu();

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        Queue<int> newQueue(MAXSIZE);
        int data;
    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        Queue<string> newQueue(MAXSIZE);
        string data;    
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        Queue<float> newQueue(MAXSIZE);
        float data;     
    }
    else
        cout << "Number needs to be 1-3." << endl;

    cout << "Enter an item to add" << endl;
    cin >> data;

    newQueue->enqueue(data);
```

Thanks everyone for the help! I almost have it done, but now that I have all virtual functions how do I call peekFront()? Since the virtual functions can't return itemType right?

Comment: Templates are evaluated at compile time. User input happens on runtime. So, the user input cannot be considered in template parameters. At best, the template can be instanced for every value which may be input by user. This is what you actually tried in your exposed sample. The issue is that the part which is not in the `if`/`else`s wouldn't compile. You could move the whole processing inside a template function which is instanced for `int`, `float`, or `string`. This reduces source code duplication but not "binary code duplication". But that's a fact in general concerning templates.

Comment: If you create a `Queue` inside a `if` block, it will be destroyed when getting out of the block, so you cannot access it from outside afterwards. Therefore, asking for data at the end is useless because `newQueue` does not exist anymore at this point. To solve your problem, polymorphism is the way to go (or `std::variant` if you can use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need runtime polymorphism to solve this problem. This can either be achieved with a base class:

```
class IQueue {
virtual ~IQueue() = default;
virtual void enqueue(istream&) = 0;
};

template<class itemType>
class Queue : public IQueue
{
//...
public:
    void enqueue(istream& is) override {
        itemType item;
        is >> item;
        enqueue(item);
    }
//...
};
```

And use as a pointer

```
int main() {
    //...
    unique_ptr<IQueue> newQueue;
    //...
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        newQueue.reset(new Queue<int>(MAXSIZE));
        int data;
    }
    //...
    newQueue->enqueue(cin);
    //...
}
```

Or something like `std::variant`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are almost there.
You just need to not loose the scope of your `data` and `newQueue` variables.

```cpp
template <typename T>
T input()
{
    T data;
    cout << "Enter an item to add" << endl;
    cin >> data;
    return data;
}
  int main()
{
    const int MAXSIZE = 5;
    int choice;

    cout << "1. integer queue\n" << "2. string queue\n" << "3. float queue\n";
    choice = menu();

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        Queue<int> newQueue(MAXSIZE);
        newQueue->enqueue(input<int>());    
    }
    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        Queue<string> newQueue(MAXSIZE);
        newQueue->enqueue(input<string>());     
    }
    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        Queue<float> newQueue(MAXSIZE);

        newQueue->enqueue(input<float>());    
    }
    else
        cout << "Number needs to be 1-3." << endl;


}
```

You still have some problem with this architecture, for example, maybe you want to move your `queue`s outside these `if`s, otherwise you can't use them anymore. (Read about [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)).

You could also look at [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for these kind of situations.